# Change default behavior in TagInput element of Buefy library (Vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

In my `Vue.js` (`version 2.5.22`) application I use UI components from `Buefy` library. I use [taginput](https://buefy.github.io/documentation/taginput) element. If I have limit of 5 tags as in example below, borders dissapear when input has 5 tags.

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to change this behavior? I want to show borders anyway.

```
<b-field label="Limited to 10 characters and 5 tags">
    <b-taginput maxtags="5":value="['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'White']">
    </b-taginput>
</b-field>
```

Comment: `.taginput-container` needs to have  `.is-focusable` class to retain border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in my case I use such style:

```
<b-field class="always-show" label="Limited to 10 characters and 5 tags">
    <b-taginput maxtags="5" :value="['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'White']">
    </b-taginput>
</b-field>
```

*CSS*:

```
.always-show .taginput-container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: auto;
    cursor: text;
    border-color: #dbdbdb;
    color: #363636;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px hsla(0,0%,4%,.1);
    padding: calc(.375em - 1px) calc(.625em - 1px);
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't prop for this. You can add a class attrib to b-field component tag:

```
<b-field class="always-show" label="Limited to 10 characters and 5 tags">
    <b-taginput maxtags="5" :value="['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'White']">
    </b-taginput>
</b-field>
```

then add a style for new class:

```
.always-show .taginput-container{
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px hsla(0,0%,4%,.1);
  border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: calc(.375em - 1px) calc(.625em - 1px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion, maybe a different way, you don't need to modify the default limit behavior:
   1. Do not limit the number of labels entered.
   2. Determine when adding, if it is more than 5, delete the first one.

- template

```
<b-field label="Limited to 10 characters and 5 tags">
    <b-taginput @add="onAdd" :value="tags">
    </b-taginput>
</b-field>
```

- js

```
data() {
  return {
    tags: []
  }
}
onAdd(){
  if (this.tags.length > 5) {
    this.tags.shift();
  }
}
```